# make the timer fire when screen is closed?

Tags: android, timer, app-inventor

I want to make a timer keep running even when the screen is closed. For example if I was to click a button that will lead me to another screen, I want the screen which just closed to keep running the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that in various approaches, for instance:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    long tick = 1000; //optional to set things during count
    long finish = 10000; //the time to count in MS
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(finish, tick) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //do thing in the ticking
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //do something when finish
        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to run AlarmManager [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html]. This will allow timers to run even when app is closed-- however I'm still figuring out how to display the AlarmManager's time on the app's UI

Answer (score 0):

If you feel confident using App Inventor, you might want to try App Inventor Services. Services allow you to have tasks for your app that can run in the background.

You can still use the clock component in services. I have tested, and the timer will work in a task, but only if the timer always fires property is checked.

If you are interested, here is a link:

http://services.appinventor.mit.edu

Here is a good tutorial to start with:

https://ai2gsoc16.wordpress.com/app-inventor-services/